# .scrollTop() in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to scroll to a position in a div, when returning back to the page of the div.
So, when I click an item in a list, the id of that item is for example 223. 
When returning back to the page, scrollTop has to go to the same position as clicked before.

I save the id of the item in a cookie.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    var id = $.cookie('LastPositionCookie');
    var rowPos = $("#" + id).position();

    if (rowPos != null) {
        $('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop(rowPos.top);
    }
    else {
        alert(id + " " + rowPos + " error.");
    }
});
```

The scroll works fine, but it scrolls from the top of the page, not from the div (tableBodyRes). How can I fix this?

**EDIT: added a picture with information**

[image]

Here you can see on the left my div with an overflow. And on the right the normal overflow of my browser. I need to go to the green item when I return to this page again.

Thanks

Comment: `223` isn't a valid id. id can't start with a number. And anyway I wouldn't use a cookie for this kind of thing, you  can store the value in a hidden input instead.

Comment: the id's are filled in with mvc3, the id of the item. He finds the id, so why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I couldn't understand your English, but the reason is simple by the spec an id can't start with a number. It might work though, but it's still not valid and might not work in all browsers.

Comment: ok, but what about my question? How can i take .top of the div and not of the whole page?

Comment: Although the id is invalid (so no CSS for you), jQuery seems to get the correct position (testing in Chrome). http://jsfiddle.net/qPhSd/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yxPQC/
I made it a litle smaller :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scroll the page to the top of an element,

```
// Swap ...
$('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop(rowPos.top);

// With ...
$('body').scrollTop(rowPos.top);
```

**EDIT**

For future reference, the issue at hand is scrolling an inner element to a position relative to the parent element (parent has `overflow:hidden;`), not relative to the document itself.

The solution we came up with was to take the inner element's top position and subtract from that the top position of the parent element.

Relevant jQuery

```
var rowPos = $("#336").position();
var divPos = $("#tableBodyRes").position();

var newTop = rowPos.top - divPos.top;

$('#tableBodyRes').scrollTop(newTop);
```

HTML

```
<div id="tableBodyRes" class="tableBodyDiv clearfix">
    <table id="tableReservations">
        <tr id="335"><td>335</td></tr>
        <tr id="336"><td>336</td></tr>
        <tr id="337"><td>337</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[And a jsFiddle for good measure.](http://jsfiddle.net/yxPQC/2/)

Comment: The problem is: 
The whole page has an overflow. And the div also. Now, I only need to scroll to a table row of the list in that div.

Comment: Yes the class is added. But no scroll to the tr. The .top value is +/- 900, so way to high for my small div. So I think it takes the top position from the top of the whole page.

Comment: I added a picture to my question. Maybe it can help you?

Comment: Ooh, ok. So you need the `tr` to be down (in my example) about 500px from the top of `#tableReservations`, not 500px down from the top of the whole page.

Comment: Yes. But when I ask tr.position().top I think I get the position from the top of the page? But I only need a scroll to the tr in the div.

Comment: anyway, the table always scrolls all to the end.

Comment: You are a hero :D The selected row is now on the top of the div :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :) For best practice, see if you can't find a way to make your `id`s not start with a number. Something like `item336` shouldn't be bad to implement and it's then W3C standard.